# Erro jasperserver snapshot

Tags: ireport, jasper

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema em meu relatorio jasper, ao tentar executar o mesmo me traz a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException:
>   No flow execution snapshot could be found with id '1'; perhaps the
>   snapshot has been removed?

Alguem sabe me ajudar com esse problema ?

Desde já agradeço